# Are there any unlock spells in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have played Skyrim for some time as a magic user, and I have by no means visited the entire world yet.

But I'm puzzled that none of the characters I have met that sell spells have any spell to unlock locks.

Is there no such spell, or have I just not found it yet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Mr. Smooth stated, there are no spells available to unlock chests or doors.

[The Tower Stone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone) effect does allow you to unlock one Expert level (or lower) lock per day.

Answer (score 11):

There's no spell that I know of, but you should know that if you have a follower, they can pick any lock on a chest, regardless of difficulty. Just talk to them and tell them you need them to do something, and then direct them to unlock the chest. [Here's](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lockpicking_%28Skyrim%29) a reference.

Answer (score 6):

There is no spell in Skyrim that will unlock doors or chests for you (sadly).

I'm afraid if you want to unlock things then you're going to have to level your lockpicking (or have a lot of lockpicks).

Comment: Or wait for the inevitable unlock spell mod.

Comment: I don't think that mod will do me much good on the console version.

Comment: I tend to double up a lockpicking enchanted ring, with a [potion of locksmithing][1] to help me get locks open.


  [1]: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Potion_of_Lockpicking#Potion_of_Lockpicking

Comment: What about the Tower Stone?

Answer (score 2):

[Midas Magic](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/3413) mod adds these spells.

Comment: Would you mind linking to this mod or providing some detail?  The more detail, the better an answer is.

Answer (score 1):

The mod, **[Ancient Spells - Morrowind and Oblivion Spells](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/9153)**, adds an "*Open Easy/Average/Hard/Very Hard locks on target*" spell under Alteration. Upon installation, you can buy these spells (given you have the skill required for them) from the usual [merchants](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants) that sell spells.

> The majority of the spells are on leveled spells merchants (this means that if a illusion spell needs a perk point on for example Master Illusion you will not see it untill you have that perk like the other spells on the game), beginner spells can be found regardless on Riverwood and Whiterun.